# showing this inequality of outer measures with set difference

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $\mu^*$ be an outer measure on a space $X$. I am trying to show that $|\mu^*(A)-\mu^*(B)|\le\mu^*({A \triangle B})$, where $\triangle$ is the set difference operator, for all $A,B\subset X$.

I have tried looking at $A-B=A-(A\cap B)$ but I think my difficulty comes from understanding $\mu^*(A-B)$

Comment: You don't need `{` and `}` after `\triangle` or `\subset` or for `\cap`. Those are not $\rm\LaTeX$ operators, just symbols.

Comment: for an outer measure, does $\mu*(A-B)=\mu*(A)-\mu*(B)?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $A \subseteq (A\triangle B)\cup B$, and so by monotonicity and then countable subadditivity,

$$\mu^*(A) \le \mu^*((A\triangle B)\cup B) \le \mu^*(A\triangle B) + \mu^*(B).$$

I'll let you finish the proof.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you.